# Rewriting a summation as a double summation?

Tags: summation, proof-explanation

How can I rewrite the single summation below into a double summation? I am trying to follow the solution to a problem, but don't understand this step.

I understand how to go from the double to the single, however.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{2^N}\dfrac{n}{2^N} = \sum_{m=1}^{2^M}\sum_{j=1}^{2^{N-M}}\left(\dfrac{m-1}{2^M}+\dfrac{j}{2^N}\right)$$

**Edit:** $M \le N$ and $M,N \in \mathbb{N}$. The equation is correct as written.

Comment: How is $M$ defined on the right?  There should be a definition in terms of $N$.  Also the summand on the left should probably be $\frac n{2^n}$.  Otherwise you can just factor the $\frac 1{2^N}$ out on the left.  A similar comment applies on the right.  Please check and get the question right.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks. See edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is to recognize that the denominators do not involve the sum variables, so can be factored out and the fact that $\sum_{i=1}^k=\frac 12k(k+1).$$$\sum_{n=1}^{2^N}\dfrac{n}{2^N} = \frac 1{2^N}\sum_{n=1}^{2^N}n=\frac 1{2^N}\frac 122^N(2^N+1)=\frac 12(2^N+1)$$ 
$$\sum_{m=1}^{2^M}\sum_{j=1}^{2^{N-M}}\left(\dfrac{m-1}{2^M}+\dfrac{j}{2^N}\right)=\sum_{m=1}^{2^M}\left(2^{N-M}\frac {m-1}{2^M}+\frac 1{2^N}\frac 122^{N-M}(2^{N-M}+1)\right)\ =2^{N-2M}\frac 12(2^M-1)2^M+2^M\frac 1{2^N}\frac 122^{N-M}(2^{N-M}+1)\
=2^{N-M}\frac 12(2^M-1)+\frac 12(2^{N-M}+1)\ =\frac 12(2^N+1)$$